# student getting an exception from Play initialization

Tags: java, playframework

I created a Play app for students to use in an assignment for my user interface course.  They don't need to modify it, just access it via AJAX.  I used "activator dist" to package it up in a JAR file;  they download it to their computers, unzip it, and run it locally.

It has worked well for everyone except one student.  I'm at my wit's end for debugging and am appealing to the community for ideas.

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getFrameworkPackages()Ljava/util/List;
at play.api.Logger$.configure(Logger.scala:268)
at play.api.Logger$.configure(Logger.scala:232)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.applicationModule(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:73)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:52)
at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

Things we've checked:
He's running Java 1.8.0_45. It was compiled with Java 1.8.0_66. He has reinstalled Java (which I'm assuming is 1.8.0_66 or greater).  No change.
The md5 checksum of the download jar file matches the original.
lib/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.1.3.jar exists and has the same size on his machine as on mine.
We've installed scala/Play/Activator on his machine, copied over the sources and tried compiling from scratch on his machine.  Same error.
I've looked in the script prepared by "activator dist".  I believe it's calling the same version of java as what we see from the command line.  That is, I don't think we're being confused by two copies of the java runtime.
This is on a MacBook Pro (pre-Retina) with El Capitan.

Ideas?

Comment: This error suggests that the problem is the wrong version of logback packaged with the app.  I have no explanation about how/why this would occur, but if you unpack what this student is using, or look at his java endorsed libs and other places that can sneak into $CLASSPATH, do you see any logback implementations there?